# Tag or pick facebook friends through IOS 6.0 social framework or Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, social-framework, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have read allot in previous threads about FacebookSDK vs SocialFramework but I cant find anything regarding the more specific area of FriendPicker.

I have a picture in my application. Right now I use SLcomposeView to post to Facebook which works great.

I now want to add the possibility to tag a facebookfriend in that picture and post the picture with the friend included.

I first followed the: [FriendPicker example - FacebookDev](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/friendpicker-ui-control/)
My LoadData function will however not load any data probably because it doesnt use the Facebook Account from settings.

I then tried the code from the provided Facebook FreindPicker example (From the FacebookSDK). I then get bounced to facebook sign in but I receive sign in error (Error: 2) probably because I am already signed in through settings?

How do I best design the application for handling this? 
Can I include "friendpicking" in the SlComposeView or do I need to remove it and only use Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you can post some of your code... Im using the following example to invoke the FBFriendPickerViewController

```
- (IBAction)addTAG:(id)sender {
if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
    // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
    self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    self.friendPickerController.title = @"Select Friends";
    self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
}
[self.friendPickerController loadData];
[self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

// Present the friend picker
[self.friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self
                                      animated:YES
                                       handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
                                           if (donePressed) {
                                               self.selectedFriends = self.friendPickerController.selection;
                                               NSLog(@"list of friends: %@", self.selectedFriends);
                                           }
                                       }];
}
```

Regards

Edited// the Scrumptious example app contains all what you need. Download the las facebokk SDK for iOS, go to samples.